# KafkaStream Vs Flink

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, apache-kafka-streams

I have used the Flink for sending data from source to sink.
My flink app consumes the data from Kafka and send to the destination.
The destination is also kafka topic which has a different topic name.
The Flink is only used for delivering purpose without having any business logic.

In this case, I think that changing the flink to Kafka Stream will increase the throughput. Because the flink has no contribution except for delivering data from source to sink. Also my source and sink uses the kafka so I think that kafka streams will be faster in case of the delivery data.

I would appreciate if you could give you any opinion for my question.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59882834/how-to-send-kafka-message-from-one-topic-to-another-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no guarantee one will be faster than the other. You still need to do JVM and network tuning.

Either will work, but the limitation of Kafka Streams is that the data must remain in the same Kafka cluster. Flink has no such limitation.

Or you can simply use MirrorMaker for moving data between Kafka topics of different clusters.

Comment: Agreed, additionally You may also consider writing simple script that does this in Python or Go or using kcat (https://github.com/edenhill/kcat).